# Parsing a .conf file with single function call in c

Tags: c

is there an elegant way of parsing .conf file in a c program? say, if i have normal text file -

```
param1 = 22
param2 = 99
param34 = 11
param11 = 15
...
```

it'd be nice to get access in one function call, smth like:

```
int c = xfunction(my.conf, param34);
```

and now c = 11. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: [libconfig](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/)

Comment: It would be better to have a function to read the whole config file into a structure once, then query the structure.

Comment: If not for the spaces around the =, you could just use putenv and getenv.  Possibly setenv with strtok to validate using strstr to ensure it is a valid param.

Comment: @technosaurus Correct me if i'm wrong: you mean converting the file's lines into environmental variables first and then reading them with getenv() calls? How do you do this conversion? I can only think of execution of the file as bash script in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better if you use a linked list as follow

```
struct node
{
  char *key;
  int value;
};
```

and assign all the `key` `value` pair to node and you can add as many `node` during parsing of conf file to the `linked list`.

later when you search you can simply traverse the `linked list` and check for the `key` by a simple `strcmp()` and get the value.

Comment: Some kind of hash map would be better than a linked list if you're using strings as keys.

Comment: Yes I agree,I suggested this for keep this as simple as possible.

Comment: mm in other words, I have to code this myself, nothing c standard - such as getopt() for command line arguments, but for conf files?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define xfunction(file, param) \
        system("awk '/^" #param " = [0-9]+$/{ num = $3 };END { exit num }' " #file)

int main(void){
    int c = xfunction(my.conf, param34);
    printf("%d\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: aha, so one option is to use system call with a bash string to parse the conf file... thanks for the idea...